# How would I calculate the quantity demanded of a product with price elasticity given and price change given?

Tags: elasticity, price

"The price elasticity of apples is -0.5. When the price of apples is $2, consumers demand 500 apples a day. If the price of apples rises to $3, how many apples will be demanded?"

I really just need help setting up the equation using the point-slope method because I'm really stuck.

Answer (score -1):

We can graph a demand curve. We have (500, 2).
Price elasticity is the effect of change in price on quantity demanded:-
[image: PED formula]

The elasticity is -0.5, which means that the change in price has a lower effect on the quantity demanded. The apples' demand is said to be inelastic.
Draw a relatively inelastic demand curve that goes through the point (500,3)

Hope it helps :)